# Printf with threads

Tags: c, multithreading, printf

I'm trying to figure out why using `printf` in my code is acting so weird. I'm using it in combination with threads, and I honestly have no idea why it's not working. I use a mutex lock to ensure that only one thread can call the printing function at a time, and this lock is shared with the function that adds variables to the list (`bbuff_blocking_insert`). Here's my code so far:

```
#include "bbuff.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct  {
    int num;
} car_t;

void *myThread(void* num) {
    car_t *car = malloc(sizeof(int));
    car->num = *(int*)num;
    bbuff_blocking_insert(car);

    // DEBUG
    bbuff_print();

    exit(0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    // Extract arguments //
    int count = atoi(argv[1]);

    // Initialize modules //
    bbuff_init();

    // Launch threads //
    pthread_t tids[count];
    pthread_attr_t attr;
    pthread_attr_init(&attr);
    int nums[count];

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        nums[i] = i;
        pthread_create(&tids[i], &attr, myThread, &nums[i]);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        pthread_join(tids[i], NULL);
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Here is the bbuff.c file

```
#include "bbuff.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 10

sem_t empty;
sem_t full;
sem_t mutex;

void* bbuff[10];

void bbuff_init() {
  sem_init(&empty, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
  sem_init(&full, 0, 0);
  sem_init(&mutex, 0, 1);
}

void bbuff_print() {
    sem_wait(&mutex);
    printf("Printing...\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++) {
        if (bbuff[i] != NULL) {
            car_t* car = (car_t*)bbuff[i]; // Convert void pointer to car pointer
            printf("%d: %d\n", i, car->num);
        }
        else {
            printf("%d: NULL\n", i);
        }
    }
    sem_post(&mutex);
}
```

And finally, heres the output if I do `./a.out 3`:

```
Printing...

0: 0
1: NULL
2: NULL
3: NULL
4: NULL
5: NULL
6: NULL
7: NULL
8: NULL
9: NULL

Printing...

0: 0

    ing...

0: 0
```

and heres another one

```
./a.out 3 

Printing...

0: 2
1: NULL
2: NULL
3: NULL
4: NULL
5: NULL
6: NULL
7: NULL
8: NULL
9: NULL
```

I would expect it to print a representation of the array like above, but with something like this:

```
./a.out 3

Printing...

0: 2
1: NULL
2: NULL
3: NULL
4: NULL
5: NULL
6: NULL
7: NULL
8: NULL
9: NULL

Printing...

0: 2
1: 0
2: NULL
3: NULL
4: NULL
5: NULL
6: NULL
7: NULL
8: NULL
9: NULL

Printing...

0: 2
1: 0
2: 1
3: NULL
4: NULL
5: NULL
6: NULL
7: NULL
8: NULL
9: NULL
```

Thanks for the help, I know this is a ton of stuff to get through so any help is super appreciated!

Comment: please create a [MCVE]

Comment: as I understand your `bbuff` is `void*` if yes, so this `bbuff[i] != NULL` Undefined Behavior since you dereference `NULL` ptr. Also, this `(car_t*)bbuff[i];` is not work how you think, it's a matter of operator precedence: ((car_t*)bbuff)[i]. To receive more help please follow to @bolov advice.

Comment: Perhaps your call to `sem_wait()` is erroring out and therefore not serializing the execution of the code inside bbuf_print()?  (since you don't look at the return value, you won't know if it's working or not).  Also I don't see any calls to `sem_init()` anywhere in your posted code, so it's possible you forgot to initialize `mutex`, or initialized it incorrectly.

Comment: I tried to make it as minimal as possible, is it not complete? 
Also sorry I forgot to add the sem_init() thing, I'll edit that in. bbuff_init() is taking care of that, and it has all the semaphores as global variables in the bbuff.c file

Comment: Just added it in, hopefully that takes care of the completeness of the question!! Thanks for the help!!!!!!

Comment: Also just so you guys know, I just rewrote my program to test it without using threads. I just copy and pasted the lines of code that add the car into the bounded buffer a few times in main, changed up a few variables, and it seems to be working normally, so the problem only shows up when threadings involved

Comment: Ideally an MCVE will be a single file and have all the necessary `#include` statements so that anyone can just copy/paste it to repro the problem.

Comment: Not to mention an implementation of `bbuff_blocking_insert()`.

Comment: Got it, I've updated it and now every copy and pasted file is runnable. I'm gonna probably cut it down once my problem is solved though, since this is for a school assignment and it might get plagiarized

Comment: You shouldn't do `exit(0);` from a thread function. You should use `pthread_exit(0)` or just `return(0);`. Whether that's the only problem is debatable. Note that `printf()` calls are individually thread-safe; while one thread has access to `stdout`, others will be blocked.  However, sets of `printf()` calls in a thread require coordination. The simplest is to use POSIX [`flockfile()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/flockfile.html) and `funlockfile()`. You shouldn't repeat `#define BUFFER_SIZE 10` in both the header and the source file (but it's "mostly harmless").

Comment: YESSSSSS it was the thing with the exit(0) that messed everything up! I changed it to pthread_exit(0) and it's working now! Thanks so much!!!!!! 

The rest of the coordination is working I think because of the mutex locks, is that good enough or should I use the flockfile() functions too?

Comment: I'm not sure whether you're using the semaphores for `full` and `empty` appropriately (and `sem_init()` generates 'deprecated' warnings on macOS, and doesn't work if you run the program — error ENOSYS, IIRC — so I have to switch to a Linux VM to test).  However, using the `mutex` should leave you safe enough.  The `flockfile()` functions are lighter-weight, probably, than the `mutex` semaphore, but that's about all.